# Calculation of rotation matrix given two vectors breaks when inverting matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a rotation in 3d (using the Euler angles) of the form:
$$ \boldsymbol{x}' = A \boldsymbol{x}. $$
Following the [mathworld from Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerAngles.html) page, this can be manipulated to give:
$$A = \boldsymbol{x}'\boldsymbol{x}(\boldsymbol{x}\boldsymbol{x}^{T})^{-1}. $$

However, the matrix $\boldsymbol{x}\boldsymbol{x}^{T}$ is singular, or at least when considering arbitrary components it seems the determinant is zero.

I am confused as to why this is since the Wolfram site makes no mention of this fact. It seems to suggest that you cannot calculate $A$ using this method? Does anyone have any ideas where I have gone wrong or if there is a better way to do this.

Edit for clarity: The $\boldsymbol{x}$ and $\boldsymbol{x}'$ are  3x1 vectors. Then the term I claim is singular in arbitrary components is:

$$ \boldsymbol{x} \boldsymbol{x}^{T} = 
\left[ \begin{array}{c} x_{1} \\ x_{2} \\ x_{3} \end{array} \right] 
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} x_{1} & x_{2} & x_{3} \end{array} \right] = 
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 
x_{1}x_{1} & x_{1}x_{2} & x_{1}x_{3} \\
x_{2}x_{1} & x_{2}x_{2} & x_{2}x_{3} \\
x_{3}x_{1} & x_{3}x_{2} & x_{3}x_{3}
\end{array}\right]
$$

$$\det(\boldsymbol{x} \boldsymbol{x}^{T}) = 
x_{1}^{\;2}(x_{2}^{\;2}x_{3}^{\;2} - x_{2}^{\;2}x_{3}^{\;2}) + \dots = 0 $$

Comment: $x$ is a 3x3 matrix (this is why they write it as capital $X$) that has all 3 vectors of a basis, right?

Comment: Isn't $x x^T$ a diagonal matrix whose entries are the squared norms of the vectors in $x$? As long as all the vectors are non-zero it should be invertible.

Comment: @Muphrid I don't think that is the case, they simply say "Writing the arrays of vectors as matrices gives" by which I thought they meant they simply considered them as 3x1 matrices? Anthony: I am not sure, perhaps I am confused as to the meaning of $\boldsymbol{x}$ but I don't think it is diagonal. I'm happy to be told I am wrong.

Comment: 2145647: I see. They're talking about doing a least-squares fit. That would make sense if the rotation is overdetermined, but using only one vector, is it not underdetermined?

Comment: @Muphrid I do not need to do the least squares fit only find A. I am not using one vector, I have $x'$ the rotated vector, and $x$ the original. The rotation matrix is composed of 3 angles so in theory we have enough information, but perhaps not to specify just A?

Comment: I said "one vector" in the sense that you have $A$ acting on a single vector and you have the image of that vector. That does not uniquely determine a rotation, so I'm not surprised that you can't find $A$ just by considering that one pair (if you will) of vectors.  (If you're confused why the rotation is not uniquely determined, you should see that for any $A$ and a pair of vectors $x, x'$, you can perform another rotation with $x'$ as the rotation axis after $A$, and $x$ is still mapped to $x'$.)

Comment: @Muphrid My mistake, sorry. So the non-invertibility is due to A not being uniquely defined? If this is the case surely you cannot then use least-squares fitting and the Wolfram page is wrong?